# How to set HoughCircles parameters automatically to detect different sizes of circles in opencv python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0

I want to set HoughCircles parameters automatically to detect all size of circles in an image. And also should detect group of same size circles.

I am trying group of same size circles in one image. And group of same size circles in different image, the sizes of circles in both image are different.

So how to set HoughCircles parameters automatically that can detect group of circles in any image.

please help me.

Thank u

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to collectively just "bin" same-size circles, the below should serve as a good starting point that can be tweaked for your application.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Test\\circles.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=2.0, minDist=50, minRadius=20, maxRadius=250)

radius_map = {}
for n in range(20, 250, 1):
    radius_map[n] = []

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        radius_map[r].append((x, y, r))

    for key in radius_map:
        if len(radius_map[key]) > 0:
            output = img.copy()
            for x, y, r in radius_map[key]:
                cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.imshow(f"Radius {key}", output)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you require some thresholded band of say, circles with radius 50 and 51 are considered the same size, you can iterate over the `radius_map` dict object and group radius bins together.

Input Image:
[image: input]

Output Images:
[image: out1]
[image: out2]
[image: out3]

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your answer. I want to detect at a time group of circles or squares or rectangle (shapes can be different sizes).

Comment: @FarzanaAnjum Your original question only mentioned circles. Detecting a variety of shapes is a different question entirely.

Comment: @FarzanaAnjum If this answer has satisfied your question regarding the circle case, please post a new question regarding the other cases and I will be happy to assist. It would greatly help in your future questions if you provide an example of expected input. Consider posting an example image in your next question, and also explicitly indicate all use-cases.